# Why I can't get the results out of my textDidChange method?

Tags: swift, xcode, search, realm

edit: I solved the problem by uncommenting searchBar delegate in viewDidLoad. Thank you

I'm working on a project on using realm. But my problem is when i search the items with this code below it doesn't make any filter and all i see is all the items not the ones i search.

```
func loadItems() {
     
    todoItems = selectedCategory?.items.sorted(byKeyPath: "title", ascending: true)

    tableView.reloadData()
  }
   
  }
//MARK: - Search Bar Methods

extension ToDoListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {


  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchBar.text == "" {

      loadItems()

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
      }

      }else{

      todoItems = todoItems?.filter("title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!).sorted(byKeyPath: "dateCreated", ascending: true)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post and format your code properly? You need to balance your curly brackets properly. There is an extra `}` above the extension and one `}` missing at the bottom of your code.

Comment: Moderators modified it already after I opened the thread. Lack of curly brackets is the reason for not understanding the question?

Comment: please take some time and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please make sure to provide a [mcve]